# Is backpropagation implemented in TensorFlow when using GradientDescentOptimizer?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

In the TensorFlow white paper it is stated that gradients are calculated on the backwards path with the chain rule. I visualised the tutorial "https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py" in Tensorboard and couldn't find out if this is actually happening.
If there is an edge in the Tensorboard visualisation, can the data flow in both directions? (normally I would expect directed edges)
[image: Graph visualisation in Tensorboard]

Answer (score 1):

Inside the "GradientDescent" box you've already seen the two "update_w" and "update_b" boxes, and you're wondering why the arrows only point in from the variables, but none out to them.

Basically, the arrows in tensorboard show dependencies, not how data moves around. A lot of the time they are similar. But it's not like matlab's simulink, if you're familliar with it. You can't have cycles in the graph.

So the arrows say: You can't run "update_w" until you have "w", "learning_rate" and "gradients".

"update_w" does update "w", there just isn't an arrow showing it.

The update doesn't go backwards along the arrow either. Consider:

```
x = tf.Variable(0,'x')
y = tf.Variable(1,'y')
set_x_eq_y =x.assign(y,name = 'set_x_eq_y')
```

Here the graph would have an arrow from "y" to "set_x_eq_y". No arrow touching "x".